# Long regex expression causes error

Tags: c++, regex, std

This

```
std::regex line("[\s]+\+?[0-9]+.[0-9]+[\s]+\+?[0-9]+.[0-9]+[\s]+\+?[0-9]+.[0-9]+[\s]");
```

line causes this

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE39E69E08 in DosyaOkuHizli.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x000000F751EFEAB0.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE39E69E08 in DosyaOkuHizli.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE39E69E08 in DosyaOkuHizli.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x000000F751EFEAB0.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE39E69E08 in DosyaOkuHizli.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x000000F751EFEAB0.
```

but this

```
std::regex line("abc");
```

does not.

The long expression works here: https://www.myregextester.com/index.php

I'm just trying to get 3 consequent floating point values between other data.

---

Visual studio 2015 community edition debug 64 bit. Windows 10.

Comment: What is the input string?

Comment: foo bar somewhitespace +123.324 somewhitespace 33434.4545 somewhitespace -3434.4545 somewhitespace biz baz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to escape the back slashes with `\\` (two for one), or use a raw string literal like this:

```
regex line{R"([\s]+\+?[0-9]+.[0-9]+[\s]+\+?[0-9]+.[0-9]+[\s]+\+?[0-9]+.[0-9]+[\s])"};
```

Raw string literals surround the string with (at least) `R"(` and `)"`.

Read more about raw string literals [HERE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) - Syntax (6).